# I need to find the value of each instrument based on the max value of the different criteria it fulfills

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have a list of instruments which have varying value. Each row has the product name and then the subsequent columns are each a criteria, these cells are filled with "yes" or "no". Each product's value is dependent on the maximum value criteria it fulfills. Put simply: the product's value is the highest value criteria. I have a separate list of the criteria and their values.

For example, if for an instrument in each criteria column there is a "yes" I need to return the max value. If only the column that signifies the lowest value criteria is "yes" (meaning all other values are "no"), I need to return that lowest value.

I need to find the value of each instrument based on the max value of the different criteria it fulfills.

This picture is an example of the main list of products and if they fulfill the criteria:
[image]

This picture is an example of the separate list of values:
[image]

The third picture is the output I would like to have, where each product has the value of the highest criteria:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `IF` to get the result you are looking for. Try the formula:

```
=IF(B2="Yes",$B$7,IF(C2="Yes",$B$8,IF(D2="Yes",$B$9,"N/A")))
```

Change the formula to reflect your columns and rows.

[image: IMG:]